# Capitalization for a bullet list

Tags: orthography, capitalization, writing, lists, periods

The following is from some software documentation we are writing:

> NOTE: Refreshing a report may be necessary or helpful when:
>
> 1. you believe the data in the report has changed since it was last executed
> 2. you'd like to return the report to its initial state/condition

My question is this. Should 'you' in the first bullet item and 'you'd' in the second bullet item be capitalized?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a matter of style. Here are two options:

---

> NOTE: Refreshing a report may be necessary or helpful when:
>
> 1. You believe the data in the report has changed since it was last executed
> 2. You'd like to return the report to its initial state/condition
>
>    ---
>
> NOTE: Refreshing a report may be necessary or helpful when:
>
> 1. you believe the data in the report has changed since it was last executed;
> 2. you'd like to return the report to its initial state/condition.

---

Create whatever rules you want for your software documentation and stick to them. As with all stylistic matters, consistency is key.

Comment: Do you think the second style above comply with [Wikipedia's Manual of Style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aManual_of_Style#Bulleted_and_numbered_lists), i.e. "when the elements are complete sentences, they are formatted using sentence case and a final period.", on this? Specifically, would it be better -- or not -- to have `1. You ...` and `2. You'd ...`?

Answer (score 4):

Bullet point items should be capitalised if the item in question is a full sentence. Likewise, in that case they should also have a full stop.

Comment: I agree, but citation needed.

Comment: it's style. there are no definitive "correct" references to cite.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that there are two possible cases.

1. Bullets may be used as part of a sentence or paragraph, in which case regular capitalization and grammar rules apply.
2. Bullets may be used as a sort of graphic communication (e.g. in a presentation) - in which case anything goes

For example, under case one, I might list

- an apple,
- a banana, and
- a grapefruit.

In this case, I am interjecting bullets into my sentence, but the sentence should remain readable. This becomes more useful with complex lists, which may refer to

- all fruit, except that which is

  - red,
  - green, or
  - yellow,

    - including, but not limited to

      - apples,
      - pears, and
      - bananas;
- vegetables;
- meat; and
- legumes, unless

  - it is the 30th of the month.

In this case, the above list is in fact a grammatical sentence, but the bulleting makes it easier to read, and as such the capitalization should maintain it's regular sentence-based form.

However, if I want to do something graphical in a document, or for a presentation, I say anything goes which effectively communicates. I might do this:

- Fruits

  - NO: Red, Green, Yellow

    - INCL. NO: Apples, Bananas, Grapefruits
- Vegetables
- Meats
- Legumes (Except on the 30th of the Month)