# Capitalize first words in a list?

Tags: capitalization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Capitalization for a bullet list](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9752/capitalization-for-a-bullet-list)

When using a list, like this:

- first item
- second item
- third item

should the first word in each item be capitalized? I.e., is this better style:

- First item
- Second item
- Third item

Does this depend on the content of the list, i.e. whether I use just keywords like in my example, or whole sentences?

Comment: Style questions are for Writers.SE.  Voting to migrate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it depends on the content - and the context - of the list. In a way you have to kind of forget that the bullet points are there and decide whether the list is part of one big sentence or whether each point is a separate sentence. For example:

(all one sentence - lower case):

> In my spare time I like to:
>
> - cut down trees
> - eat my lunch
> - go to the lavatory

(separate sentences - capital letters):

> Some characteristics of a lumberjack I know:
>
> - He's ok.
> - He sleeps all night and he works all day.
> - On Wednesdays he goes shopping and has buttered scones for tea.

Comment: Sounds like a lumberjack I'd like to know!